# div not resizing after toggle another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have this weird issue with a div1 (let's call it div1) not resizing after using a toggle jquery event to hide another div2 (let's call it div2), unless I resize the windows manually thin gis with just 1 px a manually resize it automatically reasize as supose, above here are some images to understand me better:

[image: this the normal view]this the normal view

[image: here is when I trigger the button to toogle dav little calendar over there (you notice that white space over there? its the size of the div I hide but in the other side.. weird aah?]here is when I trigger the button to toogle dav little calendar over there (you notice that white space over there? its the size of the div I hide but in the other side.. weird aah?

[image: and here when I resize manually]and here when I resize manually

now the code it's a little to large to post it here or fiddle for what that matters but, all thes is with the [library dhtmlxscheduler over here](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/) and an used with of this code may be found  [here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/05_calendar/05_plain_structure.html)

Comment: Provide your code with css